# logger.debug vs puts in Rails debugging?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I used to do `puts 'text'` in order to have a look at the flow of my code. I decided to, instead of doing that, use the `logger.debug 'text'`.

However, I don't see any text outputed in the terminal where I have run rails s. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're definitely headed the right direction in using `logger.debug` instead of `puts` as `puts` is more for command line applications.

`Rails.logger.debug`, or in short `logger.debug` writes the parameter text to a log file.  This log file is by default environment specific.  If you are currently running rails in `development` environment then the log file in use is `log/development.log`.

If you open the file `log/development.log`, you will find the debug text `text` in there.  To see the log output as they are written to the file, you can use the `tail` command (if you are in unix system) as follows in a new terminal with present working directory as your rails application root:

```
$ tail -f log/development.log
```

Answer (score 6):

**The quick answer**: The right way to debug your application is to print it to your logs (Try to avoid from scripts doing `puts 'your message'` ,instead, use `Rails.logger.info "your message"` as best practice.

**Explanation:** You have 4 types of loggers according to your environment config (production/staging/development/test), that are located in `/logs`. For example if you're debugging `RAILS_ENV=test rails s -p 5000` you would find it in `<yourApplicationPath>/log/test.log`

The available log levels are: `:debug, :info, :warn, :error, :fatal,` and `:unknown`, corresponding to the log level numbers from 0 up to 5, respectively.

To write in the current log use the logger.(debug|info|warn|error|fatal|unknown) method from within a controller, model, or mailer:

```
Rails.logger.debug "Person attributes hash: #{@person.attributes.inspect}"
Rails.logger.info "Processing the request..."
Rails.logger.fatal "Terminating application, raised unrecoverable error!!!"
```

In this way you can grep and filter the right levels and insert some logic to your debugging process. Read rails [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) for more details:

Answer (score 2):

`logger.debug 'text'` would log the text in the environment logger file. If you are in `development` environment then you can see the logs in `log/development.log`.

To see the logs on console,
For example: In development environment you can update the `config/environments/development.rb` file as below:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
config.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG  ## set the appropriate log level like DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL
```

Or

You can directly read from the environment log file like Vee suggested

```
 tail -f log/development.log
```